# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I am now working on routing after login in successfully. But got this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate')

Here is the login page

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loginName: "",
      password: "",
      loginNameError: null,
      passwordError: null,
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.navigation.navigate("/employee")
  }

  render() {
    return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="input-container">
                <label>User ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="loginName" value={this.state.loginName} onChange={(e) => (this.setState({ loginName: e.target.value }))} />
                <p>{this.state.loginNameError}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="input-container">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => (this.setState({ password: e.target.value }))} />
                <p>{this.state.passwordError}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="button-container"><input type="submit" value="CONNECT"></input></div>
            </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Here is the APP.js

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div class="page">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/employee" element={<UserManagement />}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

how to solve this error?

Comment: You are not passing `navigate` prop to `Login`... what are you using for routing? `react-router`??

Comment: @alextrastero I use react-router originally and success to route to the employee page. Now I am trying to learn and use the method of this.props.navigate to route to another page but do not know how to change the format. Is it a must to change the <BrowserRouter><Routes> to <NavigationContainer><Stack.Navigator>? or having another solution?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using a class component? react-router embraces use of hooks and for that it needs to be a stateless component

Comment: @alextrastero I don't know is it a must to change to the class component. Coz all the js files I have written are using function components. However, when I use a form for creation, edition and viewing, the data of the form cannot be updated automatically. Then, I saw a method online that says using a class component and the constructor can solve the problem. So, I change the code to class component.

Comment: Sounds like a hack... why don't you create another post with THAT issue you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Since react router v6 doesnt have withRouter

// https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it

import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}


// then in the Login class component you can consume withRouter


handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // consume `router` prop
  this.props.router.navigate("/employee");
}

// Wrap Login in withRouter HOC to make sure `router` prop is available
export default withRouter(Login);
// export default Login;
```

This said, I would recommend using react-router with a function component, not a class component.

Answer (score 0):

Because using of class component you can not use hooks!
but I think this work here:

```
this.props.history.push("/employee");
```